# Problem with carousel while loading image dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express-handlebars

I have used bootstrap material carousel. It works fine when I load image statically.Like:

```
<div class="row"  >
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="1000">
            <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="view">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(15).jpg" alt="First slide">
                        <div class="mask rgba-black-slight"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3 class="h3-responsive">First Event</h3>
                        <p>This is our first event.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(16).jpg" alt="Second slide">

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3 class="h3-responsive">Second Event</h3>
                    <p>This is our second event.</p>
                </div>

                </div>

                <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(17).jpg" alt="Third slide">

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3 class="h3-responsive">Third Event</h3>
                    <p>This is our third event.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I load images from database i.e dynamically, carousel's images splits in block view and carousel doesn't works anymore. Like when I load in this way:

```
<div class="row"  >
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="1000">
            <div class="carousel-inner">


                {{#each events}}
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="view">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="/uploads/{{file}}" alt="First slide">
                        <div class="mask rgba-black-slight"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3 class="h3-responsive">{{title}}</h3>
                        <p>{{description}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{/each}}



            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I load in this way images are seen in block view one after another instead of carousel.

[image: these are two different images loading from backend]

I can see those images but not as a carousel. I mean I am getting images from back end but they are not displayed well.
For kind information I have used node js and handlebars as template engine.

What is wrong here? I am new to node and sorry if it was a simple question.

Comment: How are you initalizing the carousel with js?

Comment: No, I haven't. I have just paste the code I found there and it was working as expected. Do I need to initialize it?

Comment: check your console log, see what is happening. It's very likely you need a js to run the carousel which should be copied over from the template

Comment: It works when loading image statically as I have shown above at first. Doesn't it mean carousel is already initialized? Moreover I don't find any javascript code there from where I copied . Console is fine too.

Comment: I have copied it from here (crossfade one):   https://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/carousel/

Comment: You should follow the steps on this link, there are plenty of files you're missing, apparently you can not only have HTML https://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/carousel/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182278/discussion-between-john-and-gugateider).

Comment: My friend you are telling carousel that all slides ar **"active"** <div class="carousel-item active">

Comment: @Roy Yes, I noticed that and it was the problem. Can you suggest me any way to add class active to only one carousel item dynamically?

Comment: Using jQuery you can $('.carousel-item:first-child').addClass('active')

Comment: @Roy You are great !! It worked as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `active` is included in all slides, that's why all of them are visible.

FIrst for all, **remove the class**  `active` in the slides, and with `jQuery` you can:
  
  `$('.carousel-item:first-child').addClass('active')`. 

https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

This will add the class `active` for the first node `.carousel-item` finded.

Hope it helped.
Cheers.